# Microsoft Graph API - Get Groups - Permission Error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get a list of groups from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups with the correct application permissions. I created an application in portal.azure.com and added application permissions (generated client secret etc). This seemed to be working but after adding and removing other permissions the application stopped working so I set up a new application (new client id and secret) with the same permissions when it was working and all expected calls are working expect https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups for which I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "adad2794-0000-43f6-812c-091acec39f7c",
      "date": "2020-03-06T12:18:58"
    }
  }
}
```

I know the GUID for one of the groups and I can call the APIs for listing group files without and problems but just can't list groups!

Is there a permission I need to add that I'm missing? I'm sure I've added the required permissions, see screenshot.

[image: Permissions Granted]
Thanks.

Comment: You trying from postman or your application? Which authentication protocol you are using? Assuming, you are using `grant_type :password`

Comment: Using client_credentials as I have created an app with a client id and secret in the portal. I have used postman and the Graph SDK. Both give the same error.

Comment: In that case it shouldn't have problem, usually problem happens for `password grant` which requires `delegated` permission, your `grant admin consent` also seems alright. Could please check your token [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io/) and make sure you have `Group.Read.All` permission there.

Comment: Could you please share how you are trying from postman? Or token request sample?

Comment: I can see the Group.Read.All permission

"roles": [
    "Group.Read.All",
    "Sites.Read.All"
],

Comment: Working for everything except https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

Comment: Just retried and it's now working!

Comment: Its working fine in my side

Comment: Strange it started working without making a change. I added the permission earlier and regenerated the access token a few times before posting this question. Do permissions take time to propagate?

Comment: Yes its take 30 second.

Comment: How do you obtain the access token? Are you getting Application or Delegated access? Your app gives Application access.

Comment: Hi, if this question has been resolved can you close the question?  Thanks.

Comment: @BrianT.JackettMSFT how do I close the question?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like [closing a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) can only be proposed by someone with over 3,000 reputation.  Might be better for either you or @MdFaridUddinKiron to post an answer with steps you took to resolve and then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try Directory.Read.All

Group.Read.All means that you can read everything about a group.